# Is it OK to delete subversion checkout in TeamCity manually?

Tags: svn, teamcity

I have accidentally checked out the root, instead of project directory using TeamCity. This file is massive (40gb+). I would like to remove this from the disk but I am unsure how in TeamCity to do this OR alternatively if TeamCity will allow me to do a good ole manual delete? The last thing I need is TeamCity dropping exceptions because I removed a check out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe. You can manually remove the file and then check out the intended project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting the working copy and then checking out the desired project directory, it will be faster to do a `switch`.  The way to do it at the command line is (from your working copy directory):

```
switch URL/to/project/directory
```